# Multiple arrays within multiple arrays

Tags: excel-formula, match

I have multiple lookup values that I am trying to match across multiple arrays. I would like to match one of those lookup values across several arrays within the same match but I keep getting "#VALUE" or "#N/A". 
Current formula I try to use is below simplified for ease of reading.

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$10,MATCH(A2&B2&C2,$D$2:$D$10&OR($E$2:$E$10,$F$2:$F$10)&$G$2:$G$10,0))
```

In this case, I am trying to match `B2` either in `$E$2:$E$10` or `$F$2:$F$10`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At first: You misinterpret the `OR` function. `OR` needs boolean values as parameters. And it will not return arrays of values, even not boolean values. It will return either TRUE or FALSE.

At second: Even if `OR` would work as you seem to think, `MATCH` needs an one dimensional lookup_array, a row vector or a column vector. It can't work with two dimensional matrices like `{$D$2&$E$2&$G$2 , $D$2&$F$2&$G$2 ; $D$3&$E$3&$G$3 , $D$3&$F$3&$G$3 ; ...}`

So simplest solution with your example would be to have one `INDEX` `MATCH` combination each possible lookup_array:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$10,MATCH(A2&B2&C2,$D$2:$D$10&$E$2:$E$10&$G$2:$G$10,0)),INDEX($I$2:$I$10,MATCH(A2&B2&C2,$D$2:$D$10&$F$2:$F$10&$G$2:$G$10,0)))}
```

Or, if you really need this the way you seem to think your formula should work, then you can't use `MATCH` and need calculate the row number on other way. For example like so:

```
{=INDEX($I$2:$I$10,MIN(IF(A2&B2&C2=$D$2:$D$10&T(OFFSET($E$2,ROW($2:$10)-2,{0,1}))&$G$2:$G$10,ROW($2:$10)-1,ROWS($D$2:$D$10)+1)))}
```

The `T` is used assuming the values in `A2:G10` are text values. If they are numeric, `N` must be used instead.

Comment: Thanks Axel. I see why "OR" does not work in this format. Also, I tried your first suggestion already and it works without a hitch. I'll give the second one a try as well, just to see. Thanks again.